# How to use search functionality with multiple fields in lightning components?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I have created search functionality in the lightning component using this link [Custom Account Searching Lightning Component In Salesforce](http://sfdcmonkey.com/2016/12/15/search-accounts-lightning-component/)

[image]

Now I need to query and display the table of data with multiple field's data what we enter like below

[image]

So here I need to add more fields in component and query in apex with the data we enter we enter in fields.

I am facing the problem with how to query in apex with multiple fields data and How to handle search button in a lightning component with multiple fields

Component:

```
<!-- CREATE ATTRIBUTE/VARIABLE-->
<aura:attribute name="searchResult" type="List" description="use for store and display account list return from server"/>
<aura:attribute name="searchKeyword" type="String" description="use for store user search input"/>
<aura:attribute name="Message" type="boolean" default="false" description="use for display no record found message"/>
<aura:attribute name="TotalNumberOfRecord" type="integer" default="0" description="use for display Number of records"/>

<!-- SHOW LOADING SPINNER--> 
<lightning:spinner variant="brand" size="large" aura:id="Id_spinner" class="slds-hide" />

<div class="slds-m-around_medium">
   <!-- SEARCH INPUT AND SEARCH BUTTON--> 
    <lightning:layout>
        <lightning:layoutItem size="3" padding="around-small">
            <lightning:input value="{!v.searchKeyword}"
                             required="true"
                             placeholder="search Accounts.."
                             aura:id="searchField"
                             label="Account Name"/>
        </lightning:layoutItem>
        <lightning:layoutItem size="2" padding="around-small">
            <lightning:button onclick="{!c.Search}"
                              variant="brand"
                              label="Search"
                              iconName="utility:search"/> 
        </lightning:layoutItem>
    </lightning:layout>

    <!-- TOTAL RECORDS BADGES--> 
    <div class="slds-m-around_x-small">
        <lightning:badge label="{!v.TotalNumberOfRecord}" />
    </div>

    <!-- ERROR MESSAGE IF NOT RECORDS FOUND--> 
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.Message}">
        <div class="slds-notify_container slds-is-relative">
            <div class="slds-notify slds-notify_toast slds-theme_error" role="alert">
                <div class="slds-notify__content">
                    <h2 class="slds-text-heading_small">No Records Found...</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </aura:if>

    <!-- TABLE CONTENT--> 
    <table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_cell-buffer">
        <thead>
            <tr class="slds-text-title_caps">
                <th scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="S.no">S.no</div>
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Account Name">Account Name</div>
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Type">Type</div>
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Industry">Industry</div>
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Phone">Phone</div>
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Fax">Fax</div>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody> 
            <!--### display all records of searchResult attribute by aura:iteration ###-->
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.searchResult}" var="acc" indexVar="count">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="slds-truncate">{!count + 1}</div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="slds-truncate">{!acc.Name}</div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="slds-truncate">{!acc.Type}</div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="slds-truncate">{!acc.Industry}</div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="slds-truncate">{!acc.Phone}</div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="slds-truncate">{!acc.Fax}</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </aura:iteration>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
({
Search: function(component, event, helper) {
    var searchField = component.find('searchField');
    var isValueMissing = searchField.get('v.validity').valueMissing;
    // if value is missing show error message and focus on field
    if(isValueMissing) {
        searchField.showHelpMessageIfInvalid();
        searchField.focus();
    }else{
      // else call helper function 
        helper.SearchHelper(component, event);
    }
},
```

})

Helper:

```
     ({
     SearchHelper: function(component, event) {
    // show spinner message
     component.find("Id_spinner").set("v.class" , 'slds-show');
    var action = component.get("c.fetchAccount");
    action.setParams({
        'searchKeyWord': component.get("v.searchKeyword")
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
       // hide spinner when response coming from server 
        component.find("Id_spinner").set("v.class" , 'slds-hide');
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            var storeResponse = response.getReturnValue();

            // if storeResponse size is 0 ,display no record found message on screen.
            if (storeResponse.length == 0) {
                component.set("v.Message", true);
            } else {
                component.set("v.Message", false);
            }

            // set numberOfRecord attribute value with length of return value from server
            component.set("v.TotalNumberOfRecord", storeResponse.length);

            // set searchResult list with return value from server.
            component.set("v.searchResult", storeResponse); 

        }else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {
            alert('Response is Incompleted');
        }else if (state === "ERROR") {
            var errors = response.getError();
            if (errors) {
                if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                    alert("Error message: " + 
                                errors[0].message);
                }
            } else {
                alert("Unknown error");
            }
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

})

Apex Class:

```
public with sharing class searchAccountController {

@AuraEnabled
public static List < account > fetchAccount(String searchKeyWord) {
 String searchKey = searchKeyWord + '%';
 List < Account > returnList = new List < Account > ();
  List < Account > lstOfAccount = [select id, Name, Type, Industry, Phone, 
Fax 
from account
                               where Name LIKE: searchKey LIMIT 500];

  for (Account acc: lstOfAccount) {
   returnList.add(acc);
  }
 return returnList;
}
```

}

Comment: SOQL is not very pratcical for your use case, you will most likely want to switch to [SOSL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl.htm)

Comment: @glls You probably should have posted that as an answer. ☺

Comment: thats fine, as long as the OP is served =)

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably want to use [SOSL (Salesforce Object Search Language)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl.htm) instead:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static Account[] fetchAccount(String searchKeyWord) {
 return [FIND :searchKeyWord IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Account(Id,Name,Type,Industry,Phone,Fax)][0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a Generic lightning Component You can use this component. It's very fast and search for any keyword in any field in the data table.

**GenericTable.cmp**

```
<aura:component >
    <!-- Attrubutes Definations Start here -->
    <aura:attribute type="boolean"
                    name="enableSearchonRow"
                    description="This attribute is used to show hide search option in tabel"/>
    <aura:attribute type="Integer"
                    name="maxRowSelection"
                    default="1"
                    description="This attribute is used to define number of row can be selected"/>
    <aura:attribute type="string"
                    name="tableHeaderTitle"
                    default=""
                    description="This attribute is used to define title for table"/>
    <aura:attribute type="List"
                    name="selectedRows"
                    description="This attribute is used to store preselected record Ids"
                    />
    <aura:attribute type="string"
                    name="panelHeightinPx"
                    default="170px"
                    description="This attribute is used to define container Height"
                    />
    <aura:attribute type="string"
                    name="headerIcon"
                    default="standard:empty"
                    description="This attribute is used to define icon in Header"
                    />
    <aura:attribute type="boolean"
                    name="showRowNumber"
                    default="false"
                    description="This attribute is used to show hide row number"
                    />
    <aura:attribute type="boolean"
                    name="showHeaderButton"
                    default="false"
                    description="This attribute is used to show hide button in Header"
                    />
    <aura:attribute type="string"
                    name="buttonLabel"
                    default="New"
                    description="This attribute is used to show label on Button"
                    />
    <aura:attribute type="string"
                    name="searchString"
                    default="false"
                    description="This attribute store search fields for row filter. Fields must be comma saperated."
                    />
    <aura:attribute name="recordSearchKey" 
                    type="string" 
                    default=""
                    description="this attribute store search string for row in table"
                    access="Private"/>
    <aura:attribute name="unFilteredData"
                    type="List"
                    description="this attribute store all data for table without filter"
                    access="Private"
                    /> 
    <aura:attribute name="lstDataRows"
                    type="List"
                    Description="attribute store Data Rows list of sobject"/>
    <aura:attribute name="lstColumns"
                    type="List"
                    Description="store Header columns property list"/> 
    <aura:attribute name="defaultSelectedRow"
                    type="string"
                    Description="store default selected row id in table"/> 
    <aura:attribute name="showSpinner"
                    type="Boolean" 
                    default ="false" 
                    access="private"/>
    <aura:attribute name="sortDirection"
                    type="String"
                    default="desc" />
    <aura:attribute name="sortedBy"
                    type="String" />
    <!-- Attrubutes Definations ends here -->
    <!-- Aura Handeler Section -->
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doinit}"/>
    <aura:method name="setPredefinedValues" action="{!c.setPredefinedValues}" access="public"/>
    <!--<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.lstDataRows}" action="{!c.setPredefinedValues}"/>-->
    <!-- Aura Handeler Section Ends here -->
    <!-- Events Regstration Sections Defiend here -->
    <aura:registerEvent name="onclickActionEvent" type="c:CmAp_LightningDataTableActionEvent"/>
    <aura:registerEvent name="onRowChangeEvent" type="c:CmAp_LightningDataTableSelectionEvent"/>
    <aura:registerEvent name="onClickRowActionEvent" type="c:CmAp_LightningDataTableRowActionEvent"/>
    <!-- Events Regstration Sections Ends here -->
    <lightning:card title="{!v.tableHeaderTitle+' ('+if(not(empty(v.lstDataRows)),v.lstDataRows.length,0)+')'}" iconName="{!v.headerIcon}" variant="base">
        <aura:set attribute="actions">
            <aura:if isTrue="{!v.enableSearchonRow}">
                <lightning:input type="search" variant=" label-hidden" class="slds-m-left_small slds-m-right_small" placeholder="{!'Search '+v.tableHeaderTitle}" value="{!v.recordSearchKey}" onchange="{!c.searchInRows}" />
            </aura:if>
            <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showHeaderButton}">
                <lightning:button class="slds-theme_neutral" variant="brand" label="{!v.buttonLabel}" onclick="{!c.handelBttonClickAction}"></lightning:button>
            </aura:if>
        </aura:set>
        <aura:set attribute="footer">&nbsp;</aura:set>
        <div style="{!if(not(empty(v.lstDataRows)),'','display:none')}">
            <div style="{!if((v.lstDataRows.length> $Label.c.CmAp_AutoHeightMaxRowLimit),'height:'+v.panelHeightinPx,'')}">
                <!-- Spinner Section -->
                <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showSpinner}">
                    <div class="slds-is-relative">
                        <lightning:spinner variant="brand" alternativeText="Loading..." />
                    </div>
                </aura:if>
                <!-- Spinner Ends Here -->
                <lightning:datatable aura:id="recordTabel"
                                     columns="{!v.lstColumns}"
                                     data="{!v.lstDataRows}"
                                     keyField="Id"
                                     selectedRows="{!v.selectedRows}"
                                     maxRowSelection="{! v.maxRowSelection }"
                                     onrowselection="{!c.updateSelectedText}"
                                     showRowNumberColumn="{!v.showRowNumber}"
                                     sortedDirection="{!v.sortDirection}"
                                     sortedBy="{!v.sortedBy}"
                                     onsort="{!c.handleSort}"
                                     wrapTextMaxLines="2"
                                     hideCheckboxColumn="{!if(v.maxRowSelection>0,false,true)}"
                                     onrowaction="{!c.rowOnClickActions}"
                                     />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="slds-box slds-theme_default slds-align_absolute-center" style="{!if(not(empty(v.lstDataRows)),'display:none','')}">
            <p><b>No data to display.</b></p>
        </div>

    </lightning:card>
</aura:component>
```

**GenericTableCOntroller.Js**

```
({
    doinit: function(component, event, helper){
        component.set("v.showSpinner",true);

    },
    setPredefinedValues : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.setPredefinedValues(component, event, helper);
    },
    updateSelectedText: function (component, event, helper) {
        helper.handleSelect(component, event, helper);
    },
    searchInRows: function (component, event, helper) {
        helper.searchInRows(component, event, helper);
    },
    handleSort: function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.handleSort(component, event);
    } ,
    handelBttonClickAction: function (component, event, helper) {
        helper.handelBttonClickAction(component, event, helper)
    },
    rowOnClickActions: function (component, event, helper) {
        helper.rowOnClickActions(component, event, helper)
    }
})
```

**GenericTableHelper.js**

```
({
    setPredefinedValues : function(component, helper) {
        let lstData =component.get("v.lstDataRows");
        let lstUnFilteredData = component.get("v.unFilteredData");
       // if($A.util.isUndefined(lstUnFilteredData) || $A.util.isEmpty(lstUnFilteredData)){
            component.set("v.unFilteredData",lstData);
        //}
        this.handelDefaultRowSelection(component, helper);
        component.set("v.showSpinner",false);
    },
    handelDefaultRowSelection: function(component, helper){
        let defaultSelectedRow = component.get("v.defaultSelectedRow");
        if(!$A.util.isUndefined(defaultSelectedRow) && !$A.util.isEmpty(defaultSelectedRow)){
            let temp =[];
            temp.push(defaultSelectedRow);
            let recordTabel = component.find("recordTabel");
            if(recordTabel){
                recordTabel.set("v.selectedRows", temp);            
            }
        }
    },
    searchInRows: function (component, event, helper) {
        let data = component.get("v.lstDataRows"); 
        let allData = component.get("v.unFilteredData"); 
        let strfieldlist = component.get('v.searchString');
        if(!$A.util.isUndefined(strfieldlist) && !$A.util.isEmpty(strfieldlist)){
            let fieldlList = strfieldlist.split(',');
            let searchKey = component.get("v.recordSearchKey");
            if(!$A.util.isUndefined(data) || !$A.util.isEmpty(data)){  
                let filtereddata = allData.filter(checkFieldsValidity);  
                function checkFieldsValidity(word){
                    let isValid=false;
                    for(let fieldname of fieldlList) {
                        if(word.hasOwnProperty(fieldname) && 
                           (!searchKey || word[fieldname].toLowerCase().indexOf(searchKey.toLowerCase()) > -1)){
                            isValid= true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    return isValid;
                }
               component.set("v.lstDataRows", filtereddata); 
                this.handelDefaultRowSelection(component, helper);
            } 
            if(searchKey==''){  
                component.set("v.lstDataRows",component.get("v.unFilteredData"));  
            }
        }

    },
    sortBy: function(field, reverse, primer) {
        var key = primer
        ? function(x) {
            return primer(x[field]);
        }
        : function(x) {
            return x[field];
        };

        return function(a, b) {
            a = key(a);
            b = key(b);
            return reverse * ((a > b) - (b > a));
        };
    },
    handleSort: function(component, event) {debugger;
        var sortedBy = event.getParam('fieldName');
        var sortDirection = event.getParam('sortDirection');
        let data = component.get('v.lstDataRows');
        var cloneData = data.slice(0);
        cloneData.sort((this.sortBy(sortedBy, sortDirection === 'asc' ? 1 : -1)));        
        component.set('v.lstDataRows', cloneData);
        component.set('v.sortDirection', sortDirection);
        component.set('v.sortedBy', sortedBy);
    },
    handelBttonClickAction: function(component, event, helper){
        let compEvent = component.getEvent("onclickActionEvent");
        let tableUniqueName = component.get("v.tableDataType"); 
        compEvent.setParams({"tableUniqueName" : tableUniqueName });
        compEvent.fire();
    },
    handleSelect: function(component, event, helper){
        let compEvent = component.getEvent("onRowChangeEvent");
        let tableUniqueName = component.get("v.tableHeaderTitle"); 
        let selectedRows = event.getParam('selectedRows');
        compEvent.setParams({"tableUniqueName" : tableUniqueName,
                             "selectedRows":selectedRows});
        compEvent.fire();
    },
     rowOnClickActions: function (component, event, helper) {debugger;
        let compEvent = component.getEvent("onClickRowActionEvent");
        let tableUniqueName = component.get("v.tableHeaderTitle"); 
        let objRecord = event.getParam('row');
        let actionName = event.getParam('action').name;
        compEvent.setParams({"tableUniqueName" : tableUniqueName,
                             "selectedRowActionName":actionName,
                             "selectedRowData":objRecord});
        compEvent.fire();
    }
})
```

**Ho to Use**

```
<c:CmAp_LightningDataTable aura:id="genericTable"
                               tableHeaderTitle ="{!$Label.c.CmAp_DevicesHeader}"
                               panelHeightinPx="350px"
                               headerIcon="standard:planogram"
                               maxRowSelection="1"
                               showRowNumber="{!v.objWrapDevice.showRowNumber}"
                               showHeaderButton="false"
                               enableSearchonRow="{!v.objWrapDevice.enableSearchonRow}"
                               searchString="{!$Label.c.CmAp_DeviceSearchString}"
                               lstDataRows="{!v.objWrapDevice.dataForTable}"
                               lstColumns ="{!v.objWrapDevice.columnForTable}"
                               defaultSelectedRow="{!v.SelectedDeviceId}"/>
```

**Here you can see UI:**

https://drive.google.com/file/d/13o9JLaz_UafbDWnnhhzo1m1oCMSgXwrR/view